# Does neo4j MERGE ON MATCH ON CREATE have a property maximum limit?

Tags: haskell, neo4j

consider a query of form

```
MERGE (x:SomeType{a:"val1",b:"val"2,c:"val3"})
ON MATCH SET x.d = "val7", x.e = "val8", ... , x.z = "val9"
ON CREATE SET x.d = "val4", x.e = "val5", ... , x.z = "val6"
```

My question is whether there is a limit to how many properties can be set? (I appreciate the database design issue regarding a model setting many properties - that's not my question).

I ask this because I seem to be hitting a limit of 12 properties set before subsequent queries for nodes results in a binary format decoding error, all using the Haskell hasbolt library. Less than this and all works fine, but I'd like to have it confirmed that I'm not falling foul of a known neo4jdb issue before investigating further.

A typical failing query would be:

```
MATCH (x:SomeType{a:"val1",b:"val"2,c:"val3"}) RETURN x
```

thanks,
S.

Comment: I think you're hitting a specific driver bug. You should open an issue there.
If you try with one of the official drivers (Java, JavaScript, .NET, Python, Go), do you observe the same issue?

Comment: Hi fbiville, yes that's my suspicion. I haven't investigated this yet, but will do so. thanks for your input.

Answer (score 0):

neo4j does not limit the number of properties to be set，
This should be a driver problem